# JQuery image wrap and toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code blow, it is use to switch an image to a second image on mouse click and also wrap a link around it at the same time. Upon clicking the image the second time it will take you to the link and also toggle back to the previous image.

What I'm trying to work out is how to also when it toggles back to the previous image is to also get rid of the wrapped link.

Also would it be possible to use the toggle on mouse click on another object. for example clicking a div on the page and it will toggle the image back to the original.

```
jQuery(function() {

    var largeLink = "<a href='index.html' target='_blank' ></a>";
    var largeLink2 = "<a href='#'></a>";
    $(".buyimage").live('click', function() {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == "buyimage") {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_5.99", "_buynow");
        } else {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_buynow", "_5.99");
        }

        $(".buyimage").wrap(largeLink);

        $(this).toggleClass("on")
    });
});
```

Comment: Just toggle the A href attribute when you change the image? this.parent().attr('href','#') and this.parent().attr('href','index.html') in your if else statement? :)

Comment: I am very new to JQuery, would you be able to actually put that as a code answer, I tried to put it i but it dident seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery `unwrap`:

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

```
// for example
<script>
  $("button").toggle(function(){
    $("p").wrap("<div></div>");
  }, function(){
    $("p").unwrap();
  });
</script>
```